# Repair pressure washer around area where hose attaches to machine

Tags: repair, pressure-washer

I have a pressure washer that I can no longer use because the area around where I attach my pressure washer hose is broken. I don't know much about pressure washers so I can't be any more helpful but I've attached some pictures of the area that is the issue. It is a Greenworks GPW 2000-1

What options do I have to fix something like this? Weld? Replace part? Epoxy?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can find a replacement part, that's the best solution, particularly if this is the outlet (high pressure) hose connection.

Comment: This does appear to be the high-pressure outlet. Attempts to fix this will most likely lead to a failure which will blow the hose off with a 2000 PSI burst, likely leading to injury or property damage. Order the replacement part(s) and install them according to the manufacturer's directions and you should be good to go. +1 for providing very good and in focus pics, though, especially the make/model panel of the washer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jwh20 answer was very helpful. After looking through the [manual](https://www.ppe-pressure-washer-parts.com/files/1961581/uploaded/GPW2000_GWPW_MANUAL_E.pdf) I was unable to pinpoint exactly what was wrong so I called the manufacturer. They advised me that the part that had to be replaced was the `motor pump assembly` and had sent me a replacement for $60 CAD (not USD!)

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share your answer. It's not surprising that you had to replace a much larger part than the little bit that broke - it's part of a much larger casting. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to the manual:

[Manual](https://www.ppe-pressure-washer-parts.com/files/1961581/uploaded/GPW2000_GWPW_MANUAL_E.pdf)

There is a parts diagram and list near the back.  It's somewhat difficult to tell from your photos vs. the diagram but it looks like the parts 20, 21, 22, 23 are involve here.

You will probably have to go to the dealer who sold you the unit and get them to order the parts.

Comment: Yes, ordering the correct parts would be best. Any rigged-up repair will be less effective in the long run. You could even try ordering the parts yourself by calling the toll-free help number plainly visible in your last picture...